# Drupal SQL query to fetch single node created on current date

Tags: database, drupal, timestamp

I have a project where I need to create a single node of a certain type for each day. How does my custom SQL query need to be formatted so that I retrieve one node data from the database where the node date matches the current date?

I am having trouble because the node timestamp in the database contains date and time info. So, I can't do a straight equality check because I can only check against the current date timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic example for D6.  You can do something like:

```
<?php
  $start = date('U', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j'), date('Y')));
  $end = date('U', mktime(23, 59, 59, date('n'), date('j'), date('Y')));

  // Database query to retrieve the node's nid
  $nid = db_result(db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE created BETWEEN %d AND %d', $start, $end));

  // Load the found node
  $node = node_load($nid);
?>
```

If your node is really simple (just title and body, etc like the basic "page" and "story" types) instead of getting the nid, could just use `db_query()` to get all of the info right from the node table.